# excel condense formulas with array

Tags: arrays, excel

I'm not really sure how to describe this

Essentially, if I want to sum the results of multiple formulas, that are essentially the same formula, but with different predictable references.

Simple example

=sum(if(a1>a2,1,0),if(b1>b2,1,0),if(c1>c2,1,0)

In my head, feel like i should be able to simplify a forumla like this, but I don't know how to make that happen

Real example:

I have this super long formula, and I feel like it be greatly simplified if I had a better command of arrays

```
=IF(IFERROR(MATCH("W",'Game Results'!D28:G28,),3)=IFERROR(MATCH("W",C28:F28,),3),1,0)
+IF(IFERROR(MATCH("W",'Game Results'!D29:G29,),3)=IFERROR(MATCH("W",C29:F29,),3),1,0)
+IF(IFERROR(MATCH("W",'Game Results'!D30:G30,),3)=IFERROR(MATCH("W",C30:F30,),3),1,0)
+IF(IFERROR(MATCH("W",'Game Results'!D31:G31,),3)=IFERROR(MATCH("W",C31:F31,),3),1,0)
+IF(IFERROR(MATCH("W",'Game Results'!D32:G32,),3)=IFERROR(MATCH("W",C32:F32,),3),1,0)
+IF(IFERROR(MATCH("W",'Game Results'!D33:G33,),3)=IFERROR(MATCH("W",C33:F33,),3),1,0)
+IF(IFERROR(MATCH("W",'Game Results'!D34:G34,),3)=IFERROR(MATCH("W",C34:F34,),3),1,0)
```

I suppose i could keep a separate formula sheet which would allow me have a simple sum of cells, but i prefer to delete the reference cells once i copy them all into one forumla.

Is there anyway to condense these when they have obvious patterns, or do you guys just keep a reference formula sheet and hide it? This just doesn't seem efficient

Edit:

Inserted picture. The cell counts how many correct picks the user made, based off of the actual results of the round(nhl playoffs) In this case, the user made three correct picks, which is accurately displayed by the formula. The issue isn't accuracy, but i feel like the formula could be way more simple. as it is essentially the same formula repeated. I feel like there should be some double array or something, or like in math i can take the array and pull it outside(like 2ab+2ac+2abc=2a(bc+b+c) the second way lets me at least stop repeating 2 and 'a' unnecessarily)

P.S i tend to over think things. I may be missing something obvious

[image: Illustration of Sheet]

[image: Illustration of thought]

Comment: The real example is kind of confusing and since you're not using exact matching, it's kind of suspicious to me. Could you maybe give a glimpse of what your spreadsheet is like (a picture would be great) and what result you're trying to achieve?

Comment: I agree with Jerry. Although I was able to answer the simple one, not sure how to make arrays of the matches.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I have added the pictures

Comment: You're doing a thorough job, but I still don't get it. Reason # 1 - your pics don't show column and row headings, so it's hard to relate back to the formula. #2, every row I see has a "W" so ... oh wait a minute, I see, you're looking a match in the relative positions. I knew that at one point! I'm going to try to solve this for a simple side-by-side pair of grids.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you explained it well. Here's an [array formula](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/arrayformulas.aspx), entered with <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>shift</kbd>-<kbd>enter</kbd>, to address your simple example:

```
=SUM(IF(A1:C1>A2:C2,1,0))
```

For your more complex example, I tried to simplify the problem. I think its:

Find the matches in the two tables where the same cells in the same relative positions = "W." I modeled it like this:

[image]

And got a count with this array formula:

```
=SUM((Sheet2!$A$4:$D$6="W")*(Sheet2!$A$4:$D$6=Sheet2!$F$4:$I$6))
```

If I'm correct then the answer to your problem is:

```
=SUM(('Game Results'!$D28:$G34="W")*('Game Results'!$D28:$G28='Game Results'!$C28:$C34))
```

Comment: Wow I need to study your mind. It seems to work. Any chance of an explanation to an idiot? It is melting my mind. Though, you need one small edit //////  =SUM(('Game Results'!$D28:$G34="W")*('Game Results'!$D28:$G28=$C28:$F34)) /////// Also this version works too /////=SUM(('Game Results'!$D28:$G34="W")*('Game Results'!$D28:$G34=$C28:$F34)) ////// As an endorsement, its something like 517 characters shorter than mine either way

Comment: Thanks! The key is that multiplication like this in an array formula is the equivalent of an "AND" operator (AND doesn't work in array formulas, at least not like you probably want it to.) The multiplication returns 1 for TRUE and 0 for FALSE. If you read through the Chip Pearson page at http://www.cpearson.com/excel/arrayformulas.aspx, he covers it there. Then the formula just sums it up. It basically ignores the row-by-row requirement, which doesn't seem to matter, and is harder. Please consider accepting this by clicking the empty checkmark next to the answer.